# Analytical solution for $\frac{e^{(2x + a)} - 1}{e^{(2x + a)}+1} = x$?

Tags: trigonometry

do you know if there is an analytical solution for $\frac{e^{(2x + a)} - 1}{e^{(2x + a)}+1} = x$?

Thank you!

Comment: No,maybe in the near future someone will succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now, there is no analytical solution and numerical methods would be required.

Starting from egreg's approach, it would be quite easy using Newton method
$$t_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} a \coth ^2(t_n)+\coth (t_n)-t_n\, \text{csch}^2(t_n)$$

With regard to the starting value $t_0$, if $a <2$ you can use from Taylor expansion 
$t_0=\left(\frac {3a}2 \right)^{1/3}$ and if, $a>2$, $t_0=1+\frac a 2$.

For illustration purposes, let us try for $a=1$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 1.144714243 \\
 1 & 1.401951708 \\
 2 & 1.381330937 \\
 3 & 1.381225364 \\
 4 & 1.381225361
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $a=4$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 3.000000000 \\
 1 & 2.995005478 \\
 2 & 2.995005229
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you set $2x+a=2t$, the equation becomes
$$
\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{e^t+e^{-t}}=t-\frac{a}{2}
$$
that is,
$$
\tanh t=t-\frac{a}{2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad t-\tanh t=\frac{a}{2}
$$
Consider the function $f(t)=t-\tanh t$. Since $-1<\tanh t<1$, we see that $\lim_{t\to-\infty}f(t)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$.

Moreover
$$
f'(t)=1-\frac{1}{\cosh^2t}=\tanh^2t
$$
Thus the function is increasing and the equation $f(t)=a/2$ has unique solution for every $a$, by the intermediate value theorem.

You can use numeric methods for approximating the solution, given a value for $a$.

If you want an “explicit” solution, call $g$ the inverse function of $f$, so the solution is $t=g(a/2)$ and therefore
$$
x=g\biggl(\frac{a}{2}\biggr)-\frac{a}{2}
$$
However, there is no expression of $g$ in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form
$$2x+a-\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)=0$$ and use calculus